# URL not re-writing as expected in apache XAMPP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, xampp

The requested url is `http://localhost/views/items?item=abc` I want to rewrite it to `http://localhost/views/myfile.php?reqtype=items&item=abc` please note that the last keyword of url before query `items` I want to move to query section as `reqtype=items` to get this I wrote below code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}           ^(.*)$
RewriteRule   ^views/(.*)$          views/myfile.php?reqtype=$1&%1 [L,NE]
```

This code is working well when I tests [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) verified its output (from this link) by directly pasting in browser as URL worked well. but with xampp (my version is 7.1.28) it is not working. Remember url-rewriting is working for other type of conditions ( means apache configuration is correct and working ) but this particular example is not working, Any solution will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. NOTE that here condition `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` is very important to stop looping else it will be keep redirecting. I have checked these rules by `curl` command and they work fine.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/views/(items)\?([^\s]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ views/myfile.php?reqtype=%1&%2 [NE,L]
```